# Using a SAPUI5 library in another project

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am currently trying to understand UI5 libraries and, for the purposes of testing, created a library project from the template that is provided in the Full-Stack-IDE.

From what I saw in various tutorials, you should now deploy the app to the SCP and then declare its existence to the app where you are going to use it. You do this by creating an entry in the neo-app.json like so:

```
"routes": [
    ...,
    {
        "path": "/resources/my/custom",
        "target": {
            "type": "application",
            "name": "testlibrary",
            "entryPath": "/"
        },
        "description": "Utility library"
    }
]
```

and in the manifest.json like so:

```
"dependencies": {
    "libs": {
        ...,
        "my.custom.testlibrary": {}
    }
},
```

However, when I do this, my app tries to look for the library under this url: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.52.5/resources/ and not on the SCP where I deployed the app. There seems to be no link between my neo-app.json entry and my manifest.json entry. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in the ui5help Slack channel. The issue was that my library needed to be declared in my index.html under resourceroots. Changing my neo-app.json like so:

```
"routes": [
    ...,
    {
        "path": "/webapp/resources/my/custom",
        "target": {
            "type": "application",
            "name": "testlibrary",
            "entryPath": "/"
        },
        "description": "Utility library"
    }
]
```

and adding this to my index.html:

```
data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
    "docgen": "./",
    "my.custom.testlibrary": "./resources/my/custom"
}'
```

fixed the problem. I will keep experimenting to see if I have to do this for every library.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the additional `resourceroots` to every consumer app (`"my.custom.testlibrary": "./resources/my/custom"`). You simply need to use `"path": "/webapp/resources/my/custom"` in `neo-app.json` as pointed out in my answer. Mine works fine without the additional `resourceroots`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom library by right-clicking on your project, and selecting **Project > Add Reference to Library**. Then select SAP Cloud Platform as repository, and include your library.

The resulting `path` in the `route` in `neo-app.json`, will be `/webapp/resources/my/custom` - this is required for running local previews in SAP Web IDE. As part of the build process when deploying your consumer app to SAP Cloud Platform, this route will be rewritten to exclude `webapp`, i.e. the path will be `/resources/my/custom`, so that it will also redirect correctly when deployed. This is working for me using `"@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build": "1.3.64"` for the build.

Using the above, you don't need to add a `data-sap-ui-resourceroots` entry per library in your consumer app's `index.html`.

Comment: But isn't the "path" parameter just what the app uses to look at the application? I thought the entrypath was what really mattered.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/aed1ffa3f3e741b3a4573c9e475aa2a4.html), `"path": "<application path to be mapped>"` and `"entryPath": "<path prepended to the request path>"`. In my understanding, the `path` represents the pattern that will be watched and redirected to the `target` when your application requests it. This redirect does not seem to work unless the full path including `webapp` is used. Have you tried `"path": "/webapp/resources/my/custom"`? Is it working?